Catching Propose New Time Event
I am developing a plugin for Outlook using C# VSTO and have come across the following problem:
When a user receives an invitation to a meeting, he/she can click on the “Propose new time” button.

Is there any way to intercept the event of clicking this button and do what I need?
And does such an event exist at all?

If it is possible, please tell me how to do it.
I tried to find something useful in the Outlook API documentation, but I couldn't find it.

No Outlook events fire when you click "Propose New Time", but when the proposal is sent, Application.ItemSend event fires and you can intercept the outgoing MeetingItem object.
